# Dynamically generated buttons passing variable value in onclick event to deeper nested functions

Tags: javascript

I'm working on creating a save dialog for a browser based game and I'm having a bit of an issue. I've got saving and listing the saves down, but I'm having an issue with loading, overwriting, and deleting. I've got the save entries created dynamically, along with the buttons for manipulating each save. Clicking any of the buttons will open a confirmation dialog, upon which clicking yes will execute the actual action. My issue lies with getting each operation to actually function on the relevant save. The code I have so far looks something like this:

```
var saveNum, buttonType;
function loadSaveList(){
    saves = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("game_saves"));
    for(var a=0; a < saves.length; a++){
        var entry = document.createElement("div");
        var buttons = document.createElement("div");
        var overwriteB = document.createElement("input");
        var deleteB = document.createElement("input");
        var loadB = document.createElement("input");
        overwriteB.type = "button";
        deleteB.type = "button";
        loadB.type = "button";
        overwriteB.onclick = function(){buttonType = 0; saveNum = function(){return a;}; saveAlert();};
        deleteB.onclick = function(){buttonType = 1; saveNum = function(){return a;}; saveAlert();};
        loadB.onclick = function(){buttonType = 2; saveNum = function(){return a;}; saveAlert();};
        buttons.appendChild(overwriteB);
        buttons.appendChild(deleteB);
        buttons.appendChild(loadB);
        entry.appendChild(buttons);
        document.getElementById("saveEntries").appendChild(entry);}}
function saveAlert(){
    switch(buttonType){
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("alertYes").onclick = overwriteButton;
            document.getElementById("alertNo").onclick = function(){/*styling to close alert*/}; break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("alertYes").onclick = deleteButton;
            document.getElementById("alertNo").onclick = function(){/*styling to close alert*/}; break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("alertYes").onclick = loadButton;
            document.getElementById("alertNo").onclick = function(){/*styling to close alert*/}; break;}}
function overwriteButton(){
    unloadSaveList();
    saves.splice(saveNum, 1, currentSave);
    localStorage.setItem("game_saves", JSON.stringify(saves));
    loadSaveList();}
function deleteButton(){
    unloadSaveList();
    saves.splice(saveNum, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("game_saves", JSON.stringify(saves));
    loadSaveList();}
function loadButton(){
    var tempSave = saves.slice(saveNum, saveNum+1);
    currentSaveLoad(tempSave);
    unloadSaveList();
    saves = [];}
```

My intention was to use `saveNum` to store the value of `a` so the bottom 3 functions know which save to operate on. I figured a closure was the way to go to get the value all the way through, but I'm honestly not quite sure how to implement it in a way that would work. I'm looking primarily for a solution in vanilla js, but failing that, an alternate way of approaching the problem would be welcome.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "getting each operation to actually function on the relevant save".

Comment: Notice that your methods which supposedly work correct (overwriteB.onclick, deleteB.onclick, etc) are invoking your saveAlert() function within the method itself? This provides the context you need. Try moving your deleteButton and loadButton functions to your switch case statement, e.g.             document.getElementById("alertYes").onclick = function(){ deleteButton()}, or even better use an async function             document.getElementById("alertYes").onclick = () => { deleteButton(); } .. this may be incorrect but you get the idea. Search threads on non-blocking vs blocking, async, etc

Comment: and also, keep in mind the scope of your application and the order of calls. Look for threads on function scopes and eliminating these context issues by using better scoping and mixing in asynchronous non-blocking functionality to tie it all up

Comment: @mentallurg what I mean is that, if I click on the button to delete save 4, or to load save 7, it will delete 4 or load 7 respectively. As it stands, delete will just remove the first entry, and loading is completely nonfunctional because `tempSave` gets a value of 0.

Comment: @HunterFrazier They do work correctly (well, deleting and overwriting do), just not on the correct save. I do see what you're saying though. Still, even if `saveAlert()` is being invoked from within, it shouldn't be an issue since it's not actually being called, right? Or am I focusing on the wrong thing here? Either way, I will check out the blocking/non blocking/async stuff in the meantime; hopefully I can figure out a way to restructure it so it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Man, it turns out I was so close. I made 2 small changes:

I changed `var` to `let` in the for loop constructor:

```
for(let a=0; a < saves.length; a++){
```

And I changed `saveNum` to accept the value of `a` itself:

```
loadB.onclick = function(){buttonType = 2; saveNum = a; saveAlert();};
```

Thanks to Hunter Frazier for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If the comment of "Hunter Frazier" helped you, be fair and vote his answer up.